# How to change tomcat default URL

Tags: tomcat

I have created Dynamic web project in eclipse, when i run the project on browser the URL is **http://localhost:8080/magicmonitor/panels.jsp** it's work fine, but my requirement is i want to change the URL dynamically, in the above URL **magicmonitor** is my project name, it's tomcat behavior it's take the default url is  http://localhost:8080/magicmonitor (Host:Port/Projectname) i want to execute same on **http://localhost:8080/dev/magicmonitor/panels.jsp** how to do that?

Comment: IMO, `http://localhost:8080/` is possible, I'm not sure if it possible to achieve what you've asked for!

Answer (score 1):

To change the URL you need to do three things:

1. Change the context root of your web project from **magicmonitor** to **dev**
2. Add the mapping **dev/magicmonitor/panels.jsp** for your JSP.
3. Clean Tomcat to remove the existing application settings and pick up the application configuration changes you have made.

Step 1 of 3: Change the context root:

- Select your project node in **Project Explorer**, right click and select **Properties**.
- Select **Web Project Settings** from the list of entries on the left.
- In the **Context root** field change the value from **magicmonitor** to **dev**, then click **Apply And Close**.

Step 2 of 3: Add a mapping for the JSP:

- Edit the project's **WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml** to add a mapping for your JSP between the submitted URL and the JSP file:

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>PanelsJsp</servlet-name>
      <jsp-file>/panels.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>PanelsJsp</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/magicmonitor/panels.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```
- That <**url-pattern**> will be appended to the context root (which is now **dev**) when matching the URL you submit. If the URL submitted from the browser matches the <**url-pattern**> the <**jsp-file**> will be called.

Step 3: To republish:

- In the **Servers** view: stop Tomcat, select the Tomcat server, right-click and select **Clean...** from the popup menu.
- You will be prompted *"Clean will discard ... Are you sure you want to clean all published resources?"*.
- Click **OK**, then start Tomcat.

You should now be able to access your JSP page using the URL http://localhost:8080/dev/magicmonitor/panels.jsp